# How to rejoin array with caught separators from .split?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below re-joins an array of words after splitting it with `/\s+/`. But it only joins it with space, replacing the original separator caught in between. I want to return the original separator caught between words, like line-breaks which are also matched on the `RegExp` expression.

```
  /** wraps URLS found in message with `<span class="hyperlink"></span>`. */
  parseURLs(message) {
    if (!message) return '';

    return message
      .split(/\s+/)
      .map(word => {
        console.log('test word:', word);
        try {
          const url = new URL(word);
          return `<span class="hyperlink">${word}</span>`;
        } catch {
          return word;
        }
      })
      .join(' ');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since each word will have its own separator (as an arbitrary number of whitespaces) you can't rely on `join` to serialize the array of words.

But if you change your parsing strategy so that instead of using `split` you go straight with regular expressions, you can match your words followed by zero or * amount of whitespaces.

```
const matches = message.matchAll(/(\S+)(\s*)/g);
```

Then you can just loop the matches found and build your own array of objects like I did here as `{fullmatch, word, separator}`.

In the end you can process this array as you best prefer and in the end serialize it back to string using for example `reduce`

*Here I also added your transform logic that will process the parsed word in `.processed` so that it will be used during the serialization process but yet you will have all the parsed bits conserved in a structured way.

```js
const o = parseURLs('test3spaces   test1space testnospace https://www.google.com');
console.log(o);

function parseURLs(message) {
  if (!message) return '';

  //regex to match nonspace characters followed by spaces
  const matches = message.matchAll(/(\S+)(\s*)/g);  

  //pushes all matches in words (as objects {fullmatch, word, separator})
  const words = [...matches].map( match => {
    const [fullmatch, word, separator] = match;      
     
    const parsed = {fullmatch, word, separator};
    //**--[This is the trasform of the word as copied from your snippet]--**
    try {                  
      const url = new URL(word);
      parsed.processed = `<span class="hyperlink">${word}</span>`;
    } catch {
      parsed.processed = word;
    }
    //**--
    
    return parsed;
  });    

  //returns the serialization of words array
  return words.reduce( (serialized, word) => serialized += `${word.processed}${word.separator}`, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've thrown away the whitespace when splitting, you don't get that back.

```
function parseURLs(message) {
  return message && message.replace(/\S+/g, word => {
    console.log('test word:', word);
    try {
      const url = new URL(word);
      return `<span class="hyperlink">${word}</span>`;
    } catch (err) {
      return word;
    }
  });
}
```